# python Assertion Error during nltk.ConditionalFreqDistribution

Tags: python, text, python-2.7, nltk

I am receiving an error I don't understand while trying to execute some python code. I am attempting to learn to use the Natural Language Toolkit via the excellent NLTK text book. While trying the following code (a modification of Figure 2.1 for my own data), I received the error below.

Code I ran:

```
import os, re, csv, string, operator
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
dir = '/Dropbox/hearings'

corpus_root = dir
text = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, ".*")

cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
    (target, fileid[:3])
     for fileid in text.fileids()
     for w in text.words(fileid)
     for target in ['budget','appropriat']
     if w.lower().startswith(target))

cfd.plot()
```

Error I received (full traceback):

```
In [6]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-abc9ff8cb2f1> in <module>()
----> 1 execfile(r'/Dropbox/hearings/hearings_ingest.py') # PYTHON-MODE

/Dropbox/hearings/hearings_ingest.py in <module>()
     14 cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
     15     (target, fileid[:3])
---> 16      for fileid in text.fileids()
     17      for w in text.words(fileid)
     18      for target in ['budget','appropriat']

/Users/ian/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.pyc in __init__(self, cond_samples)
   1727         defaultdict.__init__(self, FreqDist)
   1728         if cond_samples:
-> 1729             for (cond, sample) in cond_samples:
   1730                 self[cond].inc(sample)
   1731 

/Dropbox/hearings/hearings_ingest.py in <genexpr>((fileid,))
     15     (target, fileid[:3])
     16      for fileid in text.fileids()
---> 17      for w in text.words(fileid)
     18      for target in ['budget','appropriat']
     19      if w.lower().startswith(target))

/Users/ian/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.pyc in iterate_from(self, start_tok)
    341 
    342         # If we reach this point, then we should know our length.
--> 343         assert self._len is not None
    344 
    345     # Use concat for these, so we can use a ConcatenatedCorpusView

AssertionError: 

In [7]:
```

I include the new IPython line to show that this is the complete error. (In reading other questions, I see that "AssertionError:" is often followed by more information. In my error it is blank.)

I'd appreciate any help on understanding the error in my code! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error by creating an empty file, `foo`, and then calling `text.words('foo')`:

```
In [18]: !touch 'foo'

In [19]: text = corpus.PlaintextCorpusReader('.', "foo")

In [20]: text.words('foo')
AssertionError:
```

So to avoid empty files, you could do this:

```
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
    (target, fileid[:3])
    for fileid in text.fileids()
    if os.path.getsize(fileid) > 0   # check the filesize is not 0
    for w in text.words(fileid)
    for target in ['budget', 'appropriat']
    if w.lower().startswith(target))
```

Comment: Many thanks! This did the trick. I'm working with ~13,000 files and I wrongly assumed they all had a positive file size. I guess I should have thought of this after reading that the error occurred on the condition that the len is NOT none.

Comment: Right. Although the `AssertionError` left no message, the traceback was useful.